# HttpURLConnection set method before connection made

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Just a quick one, I have looked around and there doesn't seem to be any one else asking the same questions. But I was wondering if its possible to set the request method before the connection is opened when a new HttpUrlConnection is made.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve this? I don't think the connection is actually executed until you call `connection.connect();` so I am just curious what is your usecase

Comment: and what for? `URL.openConnection()` doesn't open any sockets ...

Comment: I'm helping to write a library to accompany a custom backend. There's an equivalent library for iOS I am using as a reference. And I was wondering if like with iOSm you can prepare the http request method with url and method until a later point when I want the request to be executed as well read the JSON back. But if you can't do it. I'll just have to alter some function calls so that the URL is prepare earlier and the connection type is requested in a later function.I think I have misunderstood the documentation with the sockets etc, find that but confusing. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

> HttpURLConnection uses the GET method by default. It will use POST if
>   setDoOutput(true) has been called. Other HTTP methods (OPTIONS, HEAD,
>   PUT, DELETE and TRACE) can be used with setRequestMethod(String).